# Open a link by clicking on link in apex oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I work in apex oracle,(and my profile is SQL), there I have a page with a list of objects, for each object there is its geo-coordinates. I want to make sure that when I click on a link (long or wide) of this object in the table, I have to open google map with a point, along these coordinates!

Before writing I wrote an appeal to a function in which I pass the function of longitude and latitude. But I cannot write the "openmaps" function itself for the transition. That is, I need help writing a function that finds a point on the map at the "LONG" and "LAT" coordinates. Thank you for your help)

```html
javascript:openmaps('#LONG#','#LAT#')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there are X and Y coordinates stored in a table. If this is a report, then you'd use something like this as a "Display" link:

```
with your_table (id, x, y) as
  (select 1, 45.13, 16.38 from dual union all
   select 2, 46.18, 15.87 from dual
 )
select
  id, x, y, 
  --
  '<a href=http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' || 
   translate(y, ',', '.') || '+' || 
   translate(x, ',', '.') ||
  ' target="_blank">Display</a>' 
  as display_link
from your_table
```

Don't forget to disable "Escape special characters" for the `display_link` column.

Running the page and clicking the "Display" link opens Google Maps and shows the position:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted, and could you clarify where you can disable" Escape special characters ""

Comment: Another question is, is it possible to make a frame in the form? To press the button to open the form with the location!

Comment: The frame itself, I added the form, but it does not change, that is, it is static, I can not understand how to make it in the form with the address that I need

Comment: Exactly, that is "another question" and you should ask it separately. Meanwhile, consider a PL/SQL Dynamic Content type region (basically, a stored procedure) which would embed Google Maps into your Apex page.

Comment: Yes, I was already interested, I tried: "begin
htp.p ('</iframe>'); end; "and added a frame from google map

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334083/open-a-link-by-clicking-in-form-iframe-in-apex-oracle I already created this question)

Comment: I've just seen it and posted an answer; have a look, please.