# Open a link by clicking in form (iframe) in apex oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

this is the second question on this topic) I have a spreadsheet where there is location. I want to click on a link in the apex table of Oracle to open a form (modal) in which there would be a frame with a point on the map at these coordinates. I have already been helped with the code, but it opens the map to me on a new page (this is good, but not convenient) I want the map to be opened in the form! I will be grateful for your help) . But since I do not understand in java script, I have to ask for help

```html
with your_table (id, x, y) as
  (select 1, 45.13, 16.38 from dual union all
   select 2, 46.18, 15.87 from dual
 )
select
  id, x, y, 
  --
  '<a href=http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' || 
   translate(y, ',', '.') || '+' || 
   translate(x, ',', '.') ||
  ' target="_blank">Display</a>' 
  as display_link
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment in your previous question, one option is to create a PL/SQL Dynamic Content type region which is a (stored) PL/SQL procedure that - as the result - runs (number of) `HTP.PRN` calls which "draw" the content on the screen.

As page HTML header, you need

```
<script 
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
  type="text/javascript"
>
</script>
```

while the procedure itself has to create something that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() 
  {
    var mapOptions = 
    { 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.67, 16.78),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var image = 
    {
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle-lv.png', 
      size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
    };
    var geocoder = new google.maps.LatLng(45.67, 16.78);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
       position: geocoder,
       map: map, 
       icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        strokeColor: "<<PAR_COLOR>>",
        scale: 3
    }, 
       title:"my_title"
      });


    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
     ];

     var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline
       ({
         path: flightPlanCoordinates,
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 1
       });

     flightPath.setMap(map);

};
</script>

<body onload="initialize()" style="font-family: Arial; border: 0">
  <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 600px; width: 800px"></div>
</body>
```

I'd suggest you to create a table which contains separate parts of code and create it *in chunks*, concatenating one onto another. Depending on what you're displaying, certain parts might require a loop.

Read what's written in this example; you'll find references to various Google API stuff so that you could research how to exactly do that.

Comment: thanks, but i don't know where to insert the second part of the code

Comment: This will be result of the stored procedure you're about to write after you do the research.